# Angular 2 templating partial components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Why i have to import all my partial components again in app.module.ts?**

Or i'm just doing it wrong?

This is my home component where i'm importing all partial components to add them to Home component.

**Home.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { SliderComponent } from "./partial/slider/slider.component";
import { AdvanceSearchComponent } from "./partial/advenace-search/advance-search.component";
import { FeatureProfile } from "./partial/feature-profiles/feature-profiles.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './Home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent{}
```

This is my app module and here i have to import all partial component again to use them. And my question is why i have to import all Home partial component here when i already include it to my home.component.ts why i don't just add them to declarations and just import HomeComponent

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { HomeComponent } from './Home/Home.component';
    import { SliderComponent } from "./Home/partial/slider/slider.component";
    import { AdvanceSearchComponent } from "./Home/partial/advenace-    search/advance-search.component";
    import { FeatureProfile } from "./Home/partial/feature-profiles/feature-profiles.component";

    import { ExploreComponent } from './Explore_spaces/Explore.component';
    import { SpaceComponent } from './Space/Space.component';

    @NgModule({

        declarations: [
            AppComponent,

            HomeComponent,
            SliderComponent,
            FeatureProfile,
            AdvanceSearchComponent.

            ExploreComponent,
            SpaceComponent
        ],

    })
```

Comment: You don't need to import them in the component, *only* in the module. If you want, you can make the component and its partial subcomponents their own module, then only have one import in the app module. Have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the `Angular RC5` you can't add components and filters to your component. The place you need to add your components is the `module`.

If you need to use those components in many different modules, import and export them in the `SharedModule`(for example), then use this module as an import to your wanted `modules`.